# get file path from stdin in C

Tags: c

I am trying to pass a file to my program however it always gives error, cannot open file.

My command is: (I am on desktop path, I am using ubuntu)

```
./out < /usr/share/dict/words > out.txt 2> out2.txt
```

Output files are created but file input seems empty. I am getting file path as:

```
char *infile;
scanf("%s", infile);
printf("file: %s\n", infile);
```

I also tried:

```
fscanf(stdin, "%s", infile);
```

Nothing changed. Also, I have to take input as shown above, I know `<` means `stdin` but I cannot read its content somehow.

This is file opening part and error message:

```
 file = fopen(infile, "r");
 if (file == 0) {
     fprintf(stderr, "File failed\n");
     return 1;
 }
```

Comment: Does `/usr/share/dict/words` exist on your system? Paste the exact complete error message into the question.

Comment: yeah this is the linux dictionary file and it exists

Comment: Are you going to paste the exact complete text of the message into the question? Also paste the output of `file /usr/share/dict/words`

Comment: (a) Eraklon is correct, you must allocate space for characters and set `infile` to point to that space before you pass `infile` to `scanf`. (b) `</usr/share/dict/words` does not give the program a standard input containing the file name “/usr/share/dict/words”. It gives the program a standard input that is that file. Reading standard input then gives the contents of the file, not its name. To read a file name from standard input, you must use a file containing a file name (or type a name without redirecting standard input).

Comment: The statement `fprintf(stderr, "File failed\n");` does not print “error, cannot open file.” Paste the **exact complete text of the message that is, in part, “error, cannot open file”**. The complete text may contain clues about the situation you are not conveying clearly. It may help to copy and paste all of the text in the terminal window from the start of the command, including the prompt, to the end of output, up to the next command prompt.

Comment: Sorry, I misled you. There is no error, cannot open file error. Just that File failed message. But also infile seems NULL

Comment: What address does `char *infile;` hold as it's value? In other words, where does the pointer `infile` point? Before you can use a pointer to store information, the pointer must point to a valid block of sufficient size to hold what it is you are trying to store. `char *infile;` creates an *uninitialized pointer* that points *nowhere in particular*. You cannot store information *nowhere in particular* -- you don't have access to that address. (and how would you find the information again if you needed to?) It's hard to get an exact address for *nowhere in particular*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be some confusion in your approach:

- you redirect input to your program from a text file containing words, the classic `/usr/share/dict/words` file. This file is the input to your program, you can read the contents with `getchar()`, `scanf()`, `fgets()` and other stream input functions, but the name of the file is not available to your program, nor do you need to `fopen` this file to read its contents.
- `scanf("%s", buf)` is an unsafe way to read a word from `stdin`. You must pass a pointer to a `char` array, not an uninitialized pointer as you do in the fragment posted. `scanf()` will write to the memory pointed to by this pointer, so an uninitialized pointer will cause undefined behavior, probably a crash.
- To use `scanf()` safely, you must provide the maximum number of characters to store into the destination array, otherwise a long enough word in the inoput file will cause `scanf()` to write beyond the end of the array, causing undefined behavior as well. Here is an example of this:

  ```
      // filtering 4 letter words:
      char buf[100];
      while (scanf("%99s", buf) == 1) {
          if (strlen(buf) == 4)
              printf("%s\n", buf);
      }
  ```

If you want to pass the path of the input file, use command line arguments.

The bash command would become:

```
./a.out /usr/share/dict/words > out.txt 2> out2.txt
```

And the `main` function:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[) {
    FILE *fp;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: missing file name argument\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: cannot open file %s: %s\n",
                argv[0], argv[1], strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    // for example's sake: filtering 4 letter words:
    char buf[100];
    while (fscanf(fp, "%99s", buf) == 1) {
        if (strlen(buf) == 4)
            printf("%s\n", buf);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`char *infile` is just a pointer and does not allocate space for the string, so the input will not be saved. Try something like `char infile[50]`. Increase the size if needed for your input.

Comment: I tried but still it does not work, I print out infile and it seems as "A"

Comment: Because you other problem is most likely what @Eric Postpischil mentioned in his "b" variant. So with `</usr/share/dict/words` what you actually say is "read the file: `/usr/share/dict/words` and give its CONTENT to my program as input" so in other word `/usr/share/dict/words` file should contain the filename what you want to open!